# How to add .dat type to apache mime.types?

Tags: apache, centos

In my limited experience with Centos8 & Apache, i find /etc/mime.types, its empty, how can i add .dat type to this file? Thanks in advance.

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please use `application/octet-stream` and test.

Comment: @Pandurang Did I try to add it but not distinguish! thanks! I'll try again!

Comment: search application/octet-stream in /etc/mim.types file and add dat extension.

Comment: Add `AddType application/octet-stream .dat` and test.

Comment: @Pandurang yes this is not success,this .dat file is zip, thanks! I'll try again!

Comment: @Pandurang The problem is solved i add AddType application/dat .dat its ok!thank you very much!

Comment: Cool!!!! Could you please accept my answer.

Comment: @Pandurang Of course! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AddType application/dat .dat` mime types and test.